# Hindi Text Lagging in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I have List of Hindi Text from `Web-service`And want to display in `UILabel`.
I am trying this using following code.

For testing I set static text Like:

```
 NSString *unicode=@"ये भी एक तमाशा है इश्क और मोहब्बत में... - ये भी एक तमाशा है इश्क और मोहब्बत में दिल किसी का होता है और बस किसी का चलता है.";

cell.lblPostContent.text = unicode;
```

In this way problem is that...My `UITableview` is not smoothly scrolling. too much lag in `UITableView`. Is there any way to display this text properly in Hindi language and also to have smooth scrolling on UITableView?
This is My cellForRowAtIndexPath........................

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

cell=(GroupDetailCustomeCell*)[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil){

        cell=[[GroupDetailCustomeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

NSString *unicode=[[post.postContent URLDecode] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    if(unicode==nil)
        unicode=[post.postContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if([post.postType isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        //textonly
        cell.lblPostContent.text =unicode;
    }
    }
 return cell;
}
```

Comment: text is in hindi or in unicode like \uxxxx?

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati try with simple text and unicode also.

Comment: can you add more code?

Comment: @AshishKakkad no more code.. only this code..

Comment: @AshishKakkad in english text work smoothly but so more laging in only hindi text...

Comment: @rameshbhuja  means of `cellForRow` code...

Comment: I have same stuff with unicode that comes from webservice, and it's not laging for me even large text, make sure you have reuse cells properly or any other thing that works on Main thread like image/thumgnail downloading or etc..

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati Yes. I am thinking about the same may be issue at the reuse of cell.

Comment: @AshishKakkad cell=(GroupDetailCustomeCell*)[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[GroupDetailCustomeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

Comment: how does a string affect the tableview scroll ? If your tablke scroll is laggy, you must be doing something wrong. Post your cellForRow method implementation and update your question. @rameshbhuja

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati share me some code for table resuable and other..

Comment: @TejaNandamuri u check my code ?

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati u check my code ?

Answer (score 1):

`tableView` component is a most hard to learn component in whole platform as 90% of iOS applications are data in a `tableView`. There are many things which could provide this incorrect behaviour. You could possibly try some of that options to fix it:

1. Most common reason for this type of problems in `tableView` is [heightForRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) method. Try to override it and count real cells height there.

Example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *yourHindiText = [NSString stringWithString:@"some text"];

CGSize yourTextSize = [yourHindiText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"SomeFont" size:someSize] constrainedToSize:kLabelFrameMaxSize];

return self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight + yourTextSize.height;
}
```

2. Try to use [estimatedRowHeight](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/estimatedRowHeight) property for your cells. As the Apple said, this property providing a nonnegative estimate of the height of rows can improve the performance of loading the table view. If the table contains variable height rows, it might be expensive to calculate all their heights when the table loads. Using estimation allows you to defer some of the cost of geometry calculation from load time to scrolling time.

   When you create a self-sizing table view cell, you need to set this property and use constraints to define the cell’s size.

Example:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0; //in your viewDidLoad method
```

3. Always use [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) method in your [cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) if you still not.

Example:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; //in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.
```

4. You may set the row height for cells if the delegate doesn’t implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method with [rowHeight](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/rowHeight) property.

Example:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension; //in your viewDidLoad method
```

There are could be more and more solutions for this problem (like using [Core Text Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) or creating layers for using GPU instead of CPU to offload it etc).
You could find plenty of possible solutions [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/uitableview/). Please pay attention on the [first one](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift).

Comment: i use like=>- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

Answer (score -1):

If limiting is not a problem, you can limit Hindi characters to improve `UITableView` scroll lag.

Here is the code to limit in swift 3.

```
extension String
{
    func limit(by:Int) -> String {
        let startIndex = self.startIndex
        let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: by)
        let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower:startIndex , upper: endIndex))
        return self[range]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.